# Web Site Administration Tool: can't enter security tab

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use the Web Site Administration Tool to set up Roles in my website.

When I try to enter the security tab I get the following error:

> There is a problem with your selected data store.....
>
> The following message may help in diagnosing the problem:  An
>   exception occurred. Please check the Event Log

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours with no success.

Here is part of my web.config:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=VicoProject___NewVersion;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\VicoProject___NewVersion__users.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MakeUpContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=VicoProject___NewVersion;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\VicoProject___NewVersion.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <remove name="LocalMySqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalMySqlServer" connectionString="" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLRoleProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <siteMap defaultProvider="MySqlSiteMapProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" />
        <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
    <webParts>
      <personalization defaultProvider="MySQLPersonalizationProvider">
        <providers>
          <remove name="MySQLPersonalizationProvider" />
          <add name="MySQLPersonalizationProvider" type="MySql.Web.Personalization.MySqlPersonalizationProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
      </personalization>
    </webParts>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: I dont knew. this is exactly what I am getting

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: The app works fine. without any errors. this error occurred only when I want to enter the security tab at Web Site Administration Tool